# Utlizing Promise To control Event Flow in VueJs

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js, sweetalert

I have a Vue directive that handles HTTP requests. What I'm trying to do is utilize promises and hook SweetAlert into the process. I am first firing off onRequestSubmit

```
    bind: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener('click', this.onRequestSubmit.bind(this));
    },
```

And in onRequestSubmit

```
    onRequestSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.fireFlashMessage()
        .then(this.vm.$http[this.getRequestType()](this.el.getAttribute("data-delete-url"), this.aggregateData()))
        .then(this.onComplete.bind(this))
        .catch(this.onError.bind(this));
    },
```

I want fireFlashMessage to return true when the user confirms so that the onRequestSubmit can delegate the request.

My question is: should I wrap the fireFlashMessage in a promise and proceed with a **then** when the calls returns successfully? I'm very new to Promises and kinda finding a hard time wrapping my head around them.

Comment: you do know your code implies that `fireFlashMessage` returns a `Promise`, not a boolean - if it returns `true` - a boolean has no `.then` method, so the code is doomed to fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SweetAlert confirm windows use a callback function, not a promise.  Then within that callback you'd use promises like

```
onRequestSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",  
            showCancelButton: true,   
            confirmButtonText: "Yes"
        }, 
        this.onRequestConfirm.bind(this)
    );
},
onRequestConfirm: function() {
    this.vm.$http[this.getRequestType()](this.el.getAttribute("data-delete-url"), this.aggregateData())
    .then(this.onComplete.bind(this))
    .catch(this.onError.bind(this));
}
```

edit: removed `this.fireFlashMessage()` as no longer using that func, although you could refactor it out again if you want